# Error String cannot be converted to boolean en métodos

Tags: java

Me está dando el error **String cannot be converted to boolean** en lo siguiente.
El programa tiene esta estructura:

```
    boolean confirmacion;        
         confirmacion = util.confirmacionPrograma("Introduce (S/N) ");        
         if (confirmacion){            
             System.out.println("Respuesta SI");        
         }else{            
             System.out.println("Respuesta NO");        
        }
```

Y en la class el método confirmacionPrograma la siguiente:

```
public void confirmacionPrograma(boolean confirmacion){
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        String respuesta = null;
        while (!respuesta.equals("S") || !respuesta.equals("N")) {
            respuesta = teclado.next();
            if (respuesta.equals("S")) {
                confirmacion = true;
            }else if(respuesta.equals("N")){
                confirmacion = false;
            }else{
                System.out.println("Introduce S o N");}
        }
    }
```

Alguna sugerencia de como solucionarlo?

Comment: Tenes muchos errores. Puntualmente el que estas consultando es porque el metodo espera recibir un boolean y le estás pasando un String ("Introduce (S/N) "). Pero también el metodo devuelve void y vos estas esperando un boolean. Y estás inicializando respuesta en null y un paso mas adelante, estas preguntando si es diferente de S o N, ahi te va a dar un NPE.

Comment: Hola Juan, Debería iniciar en public boolean entonces?, he iniciado en null porque me pedía un valor para iniciar. Lo otro es para que el while se ejecute siempre cuando no introduzca un S o N.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es quieres pasar un String en vez de un boolean. Te podría servir algo como esto:

```
    public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args){

     if (confirmacion()){            
        System.out.println("Respuesta SI");        
      }else{            
        System.out.println("Respuesta NO");        
      } 

    }

    public static boolean confirmacion(){
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        String respuesta = null;
        boolean verdadero = false;
         while (!respuesta.equals("S") || !respuesta.equals("N")) {
                respuesta = teclado.next();
                if (respuesta.equals("S")) {
                    verdadero = true;
                }else if(respuesta.equals("N")){
                    verdadero = false;
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Introduce S o N");}
            }
        return verdadero;
    }
}
```

Java es estricto a la hora de definir variables. No puedes pasar un "string" si requieres un true o false.